# Ace editor - Highlight line on mouseover

Tags: angular, ace-editor

I would like to highlight the current hovered line in Ace Editor but I can't find any samples of this and API documentation doesn't seem to mention any kind of 'mouseover' or 'mousemove' events.

Please note I'm using `Angular 8` and `Ace-builds v1.4.5`.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way using only css is to add the following style

```
.ace_line {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
.ace_line:hover {
    background-color: #a0a4;
}
```

Another way that allows more customization is to add a mousemove handler and update marker https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.4.8/lib/ace/autocomplete/popup.js#L108 similar to what popup.js does in ace.

Comment: The css solution you provided works perfectly for my needs. I tried this but I missed pointer-events: auto.